# Convert expression to LaTeX string

Tags: output-formatting, output, latex

How do I convert a Mathematica expression to the equivalent `TeXForm` string as shown when applying `TeXForm`?

For example: `toTeXFormString[\[Alpha]]` should output the string "\alpha" as a manipulable string. (It should not output `TeXForm[\[Alpha]]` formatted in string form, i.e. `toTeXFormString[\[Alpha]]<>"bla"` should append the string bla.)

Comment: Use `ToString[α, TeXForm]`.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `` Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX ``.